# Cannot execute 'spark-submit' from SparkSubmitOperator

Tags: docker, apache-spark, pyspark, docker-compose, airflow

Making life easier,

[this](https://github.com/cordon-thiago/airflow-spark) project is great for running jobs in pySpark by Airflow or Jupyter notebooks using Docker. Unfortunately, the Airflow part fails.

I guess it is because the SparkSubmitOperator can´t find the spark binaries but in the settings, everthing looks fine.

There is an open [issue](https://github.com/cordon-thiago/airflow-spark/issues) with details for that. I hope we can solve it together since I´m new to Docker-Compose and probably miss some relevant points.

Thanks for your support.

Comment: what is your error exactly? Airflow could find the spark-submit binary? please update your question with code and error message